# How to navigate with Segue in Swift

Tags: ios

I need help on navigation for my Swift App.

say, I am not using Navigation Controller or Tab Bar Controller

as I want to create a menu as below in MainVC

- BtnMenu1
- BtnMenu2
- and others

I want to use Segue to navigate back and forth.

Can some1 suggest how I can accomplish below tasks

```
               |--> N1_VC --> N2_VC
  MainVC -->   |
               |
               |--> M1_VC  -->  M2_VC
```

I have these questions:

1. How do I set Up the Segue from MainVC to N1 and M1 respectively?

   Can I have 2 button in MainVC for navigation

   BtnA - Control drag it to N1

   BtnB - Control drag it to M1?
2. How to return from N1 to MainVC
3. Can have 2 choices to return from N2 :  a) N2 to N1
                                          b) N2 to MainVC
4. When navigate from N2 to MainVC, will N1 be destroyed as well as N2?

Answer (score 0):

Just drag all 5 viewControllers to the form, drop 2 buttons in the first one "Main_VC", control drag from the button "To M1" to the second  view controller "M1" one, add a button in the second viewController and control drag from the button "To M2" to the third view controller "M2", repeat the process to N1 and N2 as indicate in the screenshot. I hope that helps you.

[image]